# Assets Uploads files but says an error occured

Tags: assets, file-uploads, file-manager

In Assets I can get a response by uploading an image to my 'files' folder, it tells me my thumbs isn't writable but it is.

When I go to upload anything else it just keeps spinning like it's doing something, but when I go to developer tools its hit a 500 error on php upload :

```
 http://hub/system/index.php?S=b7bf798211af97143dedab31f9b776ae2cb9444b&D=cp&C=content_files_modal&M=upload_file
```

My other folders I can store images in correctly as they are image only folders, and in my specific folder which is all files I can upload anything, it's just this one file.

I did have another folder pointing to the same location but deleted this, its got full access as I gave iis_usrs full access on all webserver as its an internal intranet only. 
I've disabled XSS filtering. Everything is saying it should work but it isn't please help.

Comment: Please Help, Anyone?

Comment: Can you check your PHP error logs, so we know what error exactly is the upload hitting? Is this a particularly large file, perhaps?